# Binomial expansion of matrix with negative indices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, binomial-theorem

Suppose, I have a matrix $(A-\lambda B)^{-1}$, Where $A$,$B$ are matrices and $\lambda$ is constant.  It could be expanded via the following expression:

$(A(I-\lambda A^{-1}B))^{-1}$ = $(I-\lambda A^{-1}B)^{-1}$$A^{-1}$

So my question is, under what condition, 
$(I-\lambda A^{-1}B)^{-1}$ could be approximated as $I+\lambda A^{-1}B  + ...$ ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: hint: add the second term of the expansion and you will have a better glimpse on what is involved

Comment: In simple expansion: (1+x)^-1 = 1- x+.. if(|x|<1). I am not sure about the matrices.

Comment: have a look at [this wikipedia article to start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function)